# To show two matrices are conjugate to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices A and B
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
B =
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

I have checked  basic properties such as trace, charatersitic polynomial and  are same .

I also realise that i need to find the  P

Such that $A=P^{-1}BP $

But how do i find P ? Thanks

Comment: Have you covered elementary matrices?

Answer (score 4):

If the two matrix $A$ and $B$ are similar then they are similar to the same Jordan matrix $J$; so find the change matrices $S$ and $T$ such that

$$A=SJS^{-1}\quad;\quad B=TJT^{-1}$$
so

$$A=ST^{-1}BTS^{-1}$$
and then we have $P=TS^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, you have

$$A=S^{-1}DS$$

and

$$B=T^{-1}DT$$

Then we have $$D=TBT^{-1}$$

So, we get

$$A=S^{-1}TBT^{-1}S$$

So, with $$P:=T^{-1}S$$

you have the required transformation.

Comment: What is meant by express first with second ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate process after diagonalization ?

Comment: @Peter in last step from where  has P come from

Comment: Just compare the representations of $A$.

Comment: @user35603, they are both diagonalizable.

Comment: @Peter i am confused from second last step to last

Comment: You have $A=P^{-1}BP$ and $A=S^{-1}TBT^{-1}S$, so $P^{-1}BP=S^{-1}TBT^{-1}S$. What do you have to insert for $P$, such that this equation is true ?

Comment: @Peter also is the task here is check if P is non singular , to ensure the conjugacy ?

Comment: @Peter after finding P what next is to be done ?

Comment: $S$ and $T$ are regular,therefore $T^{-1}$ is regular as well. And the product of regular matrices is regular.

Comment: We have already found $P$. That was the task.

Answer (score 3):

Compute the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. These are of course $1, 1, 3$.

Compute eigenvectors of $A$. These are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the first two are relative to $1$, and the third to $3$.

Simlarly for $B$ one has
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then you build matrices with the eigenvectors as columns
$$
\alpha
=
\begin{bmatrix}-2&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\beta
=
\begin{bmatrix}0&-2&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

You will have
$$
\alpha^{-1} A \alpha 
=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\&1\\&&3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\beta^{-1} B \beta,
$$
where I have omitted zeroes.

Therefore
$$
B = (\alpha \beta^{-1})^{-1} A \alpha \beta^{-1}.
$$